# Load my WordPress page in 3rd party webpage as overlay using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, overlay

I have a **WordPress** page "site A" that contains exit intent script and other active plugins, but I wish to have the **same functions working on another site(third party-"site B")** which doesn't provide that function.

I'm given a field where **I can insert code on "site B"** and wish to display my WordPress page as transparent layer or any other method that **enables the WordPress plugin to work in the background**.

Is it possible?